# Common Eclipse 4 Plugins in Eclipse 4 RCP Application

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rcp

Unfortunately I didn't find an answer to my question on Google and Stackoverflow. 
Is it possible to integrate common Eclipse 4 Plugins e.g. Subversion into a self-written Eclipse 4 Rich Client Application?
In my opinion there would occur a problem due to different extension-point definitions. Is this correct? 
Would it be possible to adapt common plugins to get it working in my application?

Thank you very much. I'm new to the area of plugin development.

Best regards,
Andreas

Comment: Is this a RCP using the 3.x compatibility layer and including a workspace? Or is it a pure e4 RCP (without workspace)?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I didn't develop the application so far. Actually I planned to develop a pure r4 RCP application since I don't know why I should need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a RCP using the 3.x style with a workspace you will be including most of the core Eclipse plugins with their extension points. So you may be able to use other existing plugins.

Alternatively you can use the base Eclipse core unchanged and add a new 'branding' plugin to change the name. You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point to suppress menu items you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You create a product and define it to consist of your chosen plugins. 
If the plugins you add are requiring certain extension points, they will also have dependencies configured for that. So all issues with missing extension points and missing dependencies will at the latest be found out when you build your RCP.

Be aware that commercial plugins may have licenses that restrict redistribution, and that they tend to insert themselves all over the place. So by adding a plugin you may end up with new menu items, perspectives and context menus that you may not want.

Comment: I tried to integrate the SVN plugin for testing purposes as you described - it worked properly. I see that there are many extensions defined for svn.ui Lib. How could I integrate such extensions in my application e.g. if I want to use these views? An example would be enough. Sorry for those questions, I'm not very familiar with e4 RCP and plugin development so far and still learning at the moment.

Comment: Are there extensions or extension points? Extension is when the plugin uses functionlity from other plugins, extension points is when the plugin offers others to use their functionality. If the id is svn.ui, it might be and ext. point. How to use them is beyond this questions, I suggest you start with this tutorial which will teach you the basics: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html

Comment: There are both but I mean the extensions. Sorry, I think it was a misunderstanding because I'm not an native English speaker :-) I included the org.eclipse.team.svn.ui Library. In the plugin.xml there are many extensions defined e.g. for "org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages" or "org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent". But thanks for the tip with the tutorial, I've already started to study it.